# square latest libary throws NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder error in spring boot java SDK

Tags: java, spring-boot, payment, square-connect, square

Currently, I am upgrading my Square Java SDK from version 2 to 20.1.0.20220616, but when I try to get SquareClient then it throws below error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.callTimeout(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder

My code in Java is written like below. Here, apikey is access_token of merchant which I stored in db. Also, I tried for SANDBOX environment. Can someone please help me to solve this.

 also need to find compatible versions for square SDK 20.1.0.20220616
with appropriate okhttp library which can work with above square SDK

```java
Environment environment = Environment.PRODUCTION;
return new SquareClient.Builder().environment(environment)
                .accessToken(apiKey).build();
```

Comment: You have an incompatible combination of libraries. The error suggests that the Square client requires a different version of OkHttp than you have currently on the classpath. Find out which version the Square client requires, find out why you have a different version, and then try upgrading or downgrading OkHttp (or Square).

Comment: as mentioned here in compile dependencies section https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup/square/20.1.0.20220616
i have used okhttp version 4.10.0 then also it says NoclassDefFound
can you please help me which okhttp is compatible with square 20.1.0.20220616?
or how can i find compatible versions

Comment: Check the actual dependencies on your classpath. Likely something else is pulling in a different version (e.g. use `mvn dependency:tree` to check)

Comment: thanks for helping me. as i am trying with different version of okhttp(4.10.0, 5.0.0-alpha.10, 5.0.0-alpha.4) with square version 20.1.0.20220616 but this is not succeed. also checked above versions with command `mvn dependency:tree`. if you have an idea which version is compatible can you please let me know

Comment: What happens if you use OkHttp3 4.9.1 which is actually listed for that version of Square?

Comment: That said, the error itself seems to suggest you have OkHttp3 version 3.x on your classpath. Alternatively, see https://github.com/square/square-java-sdk/issues/40

Comment: with OkHttp3 4.9.1 it throws error like 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.collections.ArraysKt.copyInto([B[BIII)[B'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246017/discussion-between-umesh-goti-and-mark-rotteveel).